Open a terminal from bash script and detect when it is closed manually
I wrote this short script to automate pcie card testing:
#!/bin/bash
BASE_DIR="$(cd "$(dirname "$0")" && pwd)"
FIRST_DIR="$BASE_DIR"
SECOND_DIR="$BASE_DIR/dir1/"
THIRD_DIR="$BASE_DIR/dir2/"
gnome-terminal --working-directory="$FIRST_DIR" -- bash -c "
    echo 'lspci pcie cards';
    ./Delete_log_files.sh; 
    lspci -n; 
    ./Load_drivers.sh; 
    exec bash;"
sleep 1
gnome-terminal --working-directory="$SECOND_DIR" -- bash -c "
    echo 'run GDMS app'; 
    make; 
    sudo ./main;
    exec bash;"
sleep 1  # Wait for 1 seconds
gnome-terminal --working-directory="$THIRD_DIR" -- bash -c "
    echo 'run GDMS app';    
    make; 
    sudo ./main;
    exec bash;"

The script work as expected. It is open 3 terminals, and execute an infinite test on terminals SECOND_DIR and THIRD_DIR. The test is executed until the user is manually closed those terminals using Ctrl+c.
My next mission is to detect in the script when those 2 terminals are closed, and execute some command.
I tried to detect when the terminals process is terminated:
#!/bin/bash
BASE_DIR="$(cd "$(dirname "$0")" && pwd)"
FIRST_DIR="$BASE_DIR"
SECOND_DIR="$BASE_DIR/dir1/"
THIRD_DIR="$BASE_DIR/dir2/"
gnome-terminal --working-directory="$FIRST_DIR" -- bash -c "
    echo 'lspci pcie cards';
    ./Delete_log_files.sh; 
    lspci -n; 
    ./Load_drivers.sh; 
    exec bash;"
sleep 1
gnome-terminal --working-directory="$SECOND_DIR" -- bash -c "
    echo 'run GDMS app'; 
    make; 
    sudo ./main;
    exec bash;"   & SECOND_PID=$!
sleep 1  # Wait for 1 seconds
gnome-terminal --working-directory="$THIRD_DIR" -- bash -c "
    echo 'run GDMS app';    
    make; 
    sudo ./main;
    exec bash;"  & THIRD_PID=$!
    wait "$SECOND_PID" "$FIRST_PID"
    ./Delete_log.sh

This script executes Delete_log.sh before both of the terminals are closed, so I guess it isn't the right solution.

Well, I don't know "gnome-terminal". But obviously from your first script (and I've just checked here too), you expect it to run in background. So obviously, it is not gnome-terminal process that you want to wait the end of, since it ends immediately

What if you provide --wait when calling gnome-terminal (while removing &). Your script should then wait until a launched terminal is closed.

I mean, in your first version, you didn't lauch them with a &. Because it is not needed, since the process last for a few milliseconds only. And the terminal itself, is obviously another process. I guess gnome-terminal program is something that tells gnome, with those bus of them, to actually launch a terminal somewhere, but isn't the terminal itself. Or that it forks itself to run the terminal and ends its main process. But whatever is the reason, gnome-terminal & pid=$! => pid is the process that lasted only a few milliseconds, just the time to ensure a terminal is started, but is not it

@chrslg Actually it probably runs the terminal process itself, but it doesn't wait for that child process to exit before exiting itself (unless you use the --wait option).


pmf, thanks. I tried to add --wait and it is working. But it is working only when I put it in the THIRD_DIR section. if it will be also in the SECOND_DIR it will block the THIRD_DIR from opening. How can I make it so the program will execute both terminals and then wait for both of them to close?


Why do you need to open terminal emulator window in the first place?

I have a script which open multiple terminals and execute pcie test between 2 cards

When the spawn terminal completes its task, it can trigger a USR1 signal to the root terminal. What you need to do is trap that signal from the root script and do the housekeeping work.
#!/usr/bin/env bash

sigusr1_received=false

function catch_sigusr1() {
    sigusr1_received=true
}

trap catch_sigusr1 USR1

gnome-terminal -- bash -c "bash -ic 'source temp.bash' ; kill -USR1 $$"&

while ! $sigusr1_received ; do
    sleep 1
    echo -n .
done
echo
echo "SIGUSR1 received"
# do something after receiving SIGUSR1


This won’t work if the script is forcibly terminated, e.g. by the user closing the terminal.
